# How to make image clickable in automatic and manual slideshows?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slideshow

I have created an automatic slide show with manual controls and i want to make images clickable too.so for that, I have put image tag inside anchor tag but it is not clickable. If anyone knows how to solve this please help.

```
<div class="slideshowContainer">
   <img class="imageSlides" src="{{ url('assets/images/1.jpg') }}" >
   <img class="imageSlides" src="{{ url('assets/images/2.jpg') }}">
   <a href="{{url('myUrl')}}"><img class="imageSlides" src="{{ url('assets/images/3.jpg') }}" ></a>
   <img class="imageSlides" src="{{ url('assets/images/4.jpg') }}" >

   <img id ="leftArrow" class="slideshowArrow" src="{{ url('assets/images/left_arrow-01.png') }}">
   <img id ="rightArrow" class="slideshowArrow" src="{{ url('assets/images/right_arrow-01.png') }}">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share a js fiddle for us to test it? Because putting all images in separate anchor tags will make them clickable by default but it could be that your slideshow js file is creating some issue. Well for any case we actually need to see some more code.

Comment: in your code you did not close the `img` tags

Comment: @HimanshuBansal https://codepen.io/t123/pen/ExjmLNJ  here is the codepen link

Comment: @PrakashReddyPotlapadu i closed the image tag but still its not working

Comment: @t123 Answered . Hope this will solve the issue ^^

Answer (score 0):

Here is manual clickable slideshow. Is this what you are looking for?

```js
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showDivs(slideIndex);
    
    function plusDivs(n) {
      showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }
    
    function showDivs(n) {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
      x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    }
```

```css
 .mySlides {display:none;}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

    <body>
    
    <h2 class="w3-center">Manual Slideshow</h2>
    
    <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
      <img class="mySlides" src="img_snowtops.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides" src="img_forest.jpg" style="width:100%">
    
      <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
      <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: actually my slideshow is working fine. The thing is i want to make the images clickable . for example if i clicked the second image it should redirect me to another  page.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response.

The slider is working fine but yeh we have to tune it a bit.

```
<img class="imageSlides" src="{{ url('assets/images/1.jpg') }}" >
```

The issue with anchor tags is because of the `absolute` position. Since the image is `absolute`, the anchor tag got no content inside making it's width and height 0x0.

```
<div class="image_wrapper imageSlides">
    <a href="sdsd" class="slide_link">
        <img class="" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" >
    </a>
</div>
```

We can contain the image and the anchor tag within a div tag and make them absolute.

**Note:** Added div tag only to give the code a better structure. You can remove them and move the `imageSlides` class to the anchor tag.

**Note:** You have to make images to fill the div tags/anchor tags. You can use the below-provided code to make image fill the div tag.

```
img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have manged to make it clickable using the counter in slideshow javascript. anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: Good that your problem has been resolved. Please share the update so others can find the solution if anyone runs into the same situation.